# Honor 4x recovery menu and factory reset not work

Tags: recovery-mode

i need help with this strange problem, i want update my phone to android 6.0 but when i start local update phone reboot and freeze on Honor logo, when i try factory reset or reboot to stock recovery menu - its same, again only Honor logo. Bootloader work ok, its unlocked, phone rooted, but when i for example try flash twrp recovery - fastboot send me "Failed...command not allowed"...Cant access recovery menu by fastboot, any app in phone and by keys combination too..also vol up, vol down and power for update from sd card not work, trying to seek for solutions to more than 2 weeks, can anybody here help me please?Thx.

Comment: How do you know for sure it's unlocked? "command not allowed" mostly points to a locked bootloader.

Comment: When i try this command...
c:\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot oem get-bootinfo
...
(bootloader) unlocked
OKAY [ 0.004s]
finished. total time: 0.006s    also in boot mode is in red PHONE unlocked...

Comment: That's weird indeed. +1 for awareness.

Comment: can you post the commands you are using to perform the above operations. (eg. installing twrp)

Comment: So i try fastboot flash recovery recovery.img - command not allowed, when i try fastboot erase cache - command not allowed, it seems like locked bootloader but when i try fastboot oem unlock - data parse fail, and i know that bootloader is unlocked, when i try update local from sd card or factory reset - phone freeze on Huawei logo, same when i reboot to recovery, it seems like broken recovery partition...

Answer (score 1):

Os installation in huawei Honor 4x

Unzip the os zip and copy the dload directory to sdcard.
press volume up + power key to switch to EMUI screen then install OS through sd card.
 OR
Press volume up and down key + power key until phone turns on then leave power key and hold volume up and down key until it show Huawei software installing.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!! I also face same issue.Try with EDL mode. Download corresponding firmware extract it. you see the dload folder copy the folder to sd card. power off mobile and press all the 3keys(power,Volume up,Volume down). It boot into Emergency downloadmode.
Firmware link: http://www.stechguide.com/download-honor-4x-marshmallow-firmware/